# Accessing preg_replace replacement references as array keys

Tags: php, regex

I have an associative array `$dic`, and I want to replace the `href` link in an HTML string with the corresponding string in `$dic`.

Here is my code:

```
$string = preg_replace("/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/s", "$2->{$dic["$1"]}", $string);
```

The above regular expression doesn't work as intended. But in this form it works:

```
$string = preg_replace("/<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/s", "$2->$1", $string);
```

I want to store the `<a>` tags as `LinkText->LinkFromDic`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"$1"` within the [*complex expression*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) `{$dic["$1"]}` is interpreted as literal string `"$1"`, because:

- the complex expression is processed *before* the `preg_replace` replacement
  references are applied;
- `$1` is an invalid [variable name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) in PHP:

  > A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores.

It is easy to verify that:

```php
$dic = ['$1' => 'Dollar One'];
var_dump("{$dic["$1"]}");
```

*Output*

```
string(10) "Dollar One"
```

Older PHP versions supported [`e`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval) regular expression modifier, which allowed to evaluate the replacement string as PHP code. But it was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0.

However, `php_replace_callback` function is flexible enough to fix the problem:

```
$dic = ['/page/a' => 'Page A'];

$string = <<<'EOHTML'
<a href="/page/a">Link</a>
EOHTML;

$string = preg_replace_callback('/<a href\="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/a>/s',
  function ($matches) use ($dic) {
    $v = isset($dic[$matches[1]]) ? $dic[$matches[1]] : $matches[1];
  return count($matches == 3) ? "{$matches[2]}->$v" : $matches[0];
}, $string);

var_dump($string);
```

*Output*

```
string(12) "Link->Page A"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how to get the value from $dic variable. Output should be "Link->Page A"